# Организация передачи различных изображений в одно ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Задача у меня такая: выводить изображения цифр вверху в центре экрана. Для каждой каждой цифры отдельный imageView выбрал, чтобы с помощью верстки задать расстояния между ними, чтобы на всех экранах выглядело одинаково. Поэтому вместо того,чтобы рисовать на канвас , я при каждой новой отрисовке передаю в ImageView новое изображение : `imageView1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.zero);` Во первых будет ли всё нормально отображаться? Если работаем с канвасом то он блокируется, рисуется и разблокируется. А тут тупо передаю новое изображение. Ну это я на деле выясню. Вопрос основной в другом. я методом Treadchronometer.getSeconds1() получаю текущую секунду в int. и если вернет 1 , то мне надо вывести изображение единички, вернет два - изображение двойки. Если через канвас , то проблем не было `canvas.drawBitmap(myArray[Treadchronometer.getSeconds1()],menu.getWidth()*0.5F, 1,null);`  а setImageResource изображение из массива не принимает, просит Bitmap вместо int.  Какое можно придумать решение?  Ну а основная цель у меня расположить несколько изображений секундомера на требуемых интервалах и чтобы везде так выглядело, поэтому я решил что линейный лояут с imageView мне может поможет.

Comment: setImageResource() не может просить Bitmap вместо int.

Comment: и, пожалуйста, задавайте вопросы точнее. если у вас проблема с выводом изображения в ImageView, зачем в вопросе все остальные подробности?

Comment: Все остальные подробности за тем , чтобы более опытный в этом человек подсказал, если вдруг мой подход в принципе не верный. Если же я вопрос задам конкретный, то возможно для моего случая это вообще не приемлимо. Поэтому в вопросе описаны и конкретная ситуация и текущая проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setImageResource (int resId)
```

как видите этот метод на вход требует int айди ресурса.  И когда в него я передаю битмап из массива битмапов , он просит int вместо android.grafics.Bitmap  . А вот зато есть метод setImageBitmap , который принимает bitmap.